# Having issues using multiple UpdatePanles in single form

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I am using Asp.net  web forms with Framweork 4.0, I've 6 updaed panels in my form and working fine on local host but when i uploaded it on server it is throwing error

"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server."

This is my page

[image]

I tries to insert data it just works 3 or 4 times fine then it starts throwing this error and everything in the page stops working.

You can check it here
[enter link description here](http://adminpanel.1mlabs.com/)

user and password is "admin"

go to "Category / Brand"

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your site. I was able to insert once. Second time, it didn't work. I looked at "inspect element" in Chrome and this is the error I see

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Validation of
>   viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or
>   cluster, ensure that  configuration sp......55

Do you have a form like this?

```
<form runat="server" action="page.aspx">
```

If so, remove the "action" part and try again.

I think you can also do this:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never" />
```

Comment: No I dont have action tag on my form, My form tag is <form runat="server">

Comment: I tried adding <page> which you told me, now the error is different.

`ScriptResource.axd?d=F4OgseePQnjQW2cfzgLBx-uXsOlDrsmxZoft411OSZQHwuDgpkPg_5a8on3DqcRVWI3-c1EWCe2HMu…:940`

Comment: One thing more, this is only happening after uploading site to server, it is still working perfect on LocalHost

Answer (score 0):

Adding machine key to web.config worked for me